# Microsoft azure redis cache with DNX core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis, dnx

Trying to use redis azure cache with an ASP.NET 5 application.
In my dependencies :

```
 "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
"StackExchange.Redis": "1.0.450"
},

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Code such as :

```
private readonly IDatabase _cache;
private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer _connection;
```

doesn't compile... If I remove dnxcore50 framework, it's ok.

Any tips to have redis azure working with dnxcore50 ?

Comment: StackExchange.Redis hasn't been updated for DNX Core - there is an issue here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/202

Comment: arghh too bad, ok. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`StackExchange.Redis` support for DNX Core is in progress](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/328). You can use it already with their prerelease versions.

[Microsoft references it in Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Redis](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis/project.json), but is currently only targeted for framework 4.5.1.

As another note, unless you're doing something specific with Redis, I suggest you look at the Caching framework interfaces; this will let you vary to other technologies for your caching solution, and won't require you to write as much adapter code to integrate it with ASP.Net.  (Of course, I usually do specific things with Redis, so I don't follow this myself; take it with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @ZOXEXIVO - I updated my answer.